# Backbone treat model like collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Since Collections is actually a model, it has attributes and so on, like in this example

```
var Images = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4v2d8'
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('.images'), 

  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render, this); // what is this keyword as the last param here?
  },

  render: function(){

    this.collection.each(function(model){
      this.$el.append($('<p>'+model.get('name')+'</>' ));
    }, this);

  }
});

$(function(){

  var images = new View({ collection: new Images() });

  images.collection.fetch();

});
```

http://jsbin.com/gohedeguto/edit?html,js,output

But why this one doesn't work?

http://jsbin.com/seyoyeqeku/edit?html,js,output

I replaced `Collection` with `Model` and passed to the View. I got `this.model.each of undefined`.

Comment: *"Since Collections is actually a model"* - what? Where/how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: actually a fake account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since Collections is actually a model

No. This is wrong assumption. Collection is not a model which is why your code doesn't work.

Model does not have an each method and your code throws following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.model.each is not a function(…)
```

and don't follow the other answer that iterates over model properties and prints it's name, it doesn't make sense. Because model is supposed to represent an entity, like a person. It'll only have one property containing name, there's no point in iterating over model properties to access one of them, you can directly access it's attributes with `get()` method without having to iterate.

Comment: In this case model returns list

Comment: @V.S.V Then you should access the property using `get()` first, and then iterate over it using `_.each()` (or whatever loop you like) to access items. From the point of models view, it's just another property...

Comment: And what will u got from model.get() wich list item?

Comment: @V.S.V That end point is returning an **Array** of items. You need a **Collection** of models for that, not a single model. Model is for single item.

Comment: I know I just write model wich will work like collection(its a bad practice). I just write way what will work in his case and sorry for downvote i will change it:)

Comment: model will always be single item?

Comment: @Sandy Think of model as a representation of a row in database (So it represents a single item/entry/entity whatever you call it). It might have attributes that are lists (think of foreign keys). And think of collection as the representation of the entire table in the db, with a model for each row in it...

Answer (score 2):

While [T-J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263712/1218980) is right, he doesn't elaborate on why.

A **Backbone model** has lots of functions to manage an [`attributes` hash](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes), and is often referenced by an id.

A **Backbone collection** is an array of Backbone model instances. It has some similar and lots of different functions to manage its [`models` array property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) which is where the model instances are stored.

Some of these functions are proxies to [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) functions.

## [Model's Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods)

- keys
- values
- pairs
- invert
- pick
- omit
- chain
- isEmpty

## [Collection's Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)

46 in total at the moment, see the list.

---

```
collection.each(iteratee, [context])
```

is a proxy to [`_.each(collection.models, iteratee, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Backbone's Model do not have a `each` function because it doesn't really make sense and there are better ways to loop through the attributes of a model.

Comment: plz check this link https://api.myjson.com/bins/4v2d8 I dont say that he is wrong , just check

Comment: @V.S.V Yeah I've seen it, standard array of models to be passed to a collection. What have I missed?

Comment: Have you read the question? This guy wants to change it to model(not collection)@Emile Bergeron

Comment: @V.S.V I totally read the question and it doesn't really explain what Sandy wants, just that _`this.model.each` is undefined._ Your answer just wrongly uses a model like a collection. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry my  fault :(